# write the same data into many lines in text file python

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

I would like to write the same information for many lines into a text file. Basicly, I have a list of numbers. I want to write these number in one line and then copy the first line to the next 400 lines.

My code at the moment is

```
outfile = open(outfilename+'.dat','w')
for j in range (0,len(elevation_list)):
    outfile.write(elevation_list[j]+' ')
outfile.close()
```

And it only writes the first line.

For example, my elevation list is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
I want my text file like the following

1  2  3  4  5

1  2  3  4  5

1  2  3  4  5

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any line breaks in your elevation list? Try this instead:

```
elevations = ""
for elevation in elevation_list:
    elevations+= elevation

outfile = open(outfilename+'.dat','w')
for i in range(400):
    outfile.write(elevations +'\n')

outfile.close()
```

Comment: No I don't want line breaks in my elevation list. I've just edited my question above to make it clearer.

Comment: Why not just build a string of elevations and repeat it as many times as you need? See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another thing is how can I add space between elevation values in my list? at the moment it writes "12345"

Comment: just change how you build your elevations string. Append elevation + ' ' instead of just elevation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
class RepeatedWrite(object):

    def __init__(self, elevation_list, no_of_lines=5, outfilename="outfile.dat"):
        self.elevation_list = elevation_list
        self.no_of_lines = no_of_lines
        self.outfilename = outfilename

    def write_to_file(self):
        with open(self.outfilename, 'w') as fp:
            for i in xrange(self.no_of_lines):
                fp.write(' '.join([str(ele) for ele in self.elevation_list]))
                fp.write("\n")


elevation_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

RepeatedWrite(elevation_list).write_to_file()
```